# Smooth scrolling and highlighted navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation, smooth-scrolling

On my site http://goo.gl/34oQ8 I have implemented a smooth scrolling with highlighted navigation based on this tutorial http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/
Works fine without the "Contact Us" item but doesn't work with it (only the "Contact us" menu item gets higlighted). Would you know why? Suspect that it's linked to the #inline ref - tks

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="current"><a href="#presentation">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#equipe">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#plan-activite">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#medias">Press</a></li>
  <li><a href="#inline" class="modalbox">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i think the issue might be with modalbox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the one-page-navigation plugin isn't handling hidden elements.  When it initializes, it computes the vertical position of each of your elements with this line:

```
self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos) - self.config.scrollOffset;
```

However, your hidden #inline element has a vertical position of 0, which throws off the current section detection code.

You would fix this by making it so that when the page loads, the position of the hidden inline element isn't 0.  I'd suggest not using a modal dialog for the contact form - just use a regular form centered in a div.

To see the fix without a code change, put a breakpoint at line 126 in jquery.nav.js, using chrome developer tools or similar.  Then, run 'this.sections.inline = 5000;' in the console.  Remove your breakpoint, and the navigation updates properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a possibility to hard-code de inline 5000 somewhere to solve the issue? Many thanks